# How to put in color a certain part of the background in a plot with matlab?

Tags: matlab, graph, background, plot

I would like to draw in grey color a certain part of the background in a plot.
I know how to change the background color of the whole plot.I used this code 
after the plot function:

HANDLE = gca

get( HANDLE );

set( HANDLE, 'Color', [0.7,0.7,0.7] )

Exemple: y=x^2

How can I do to draw the blue part of the background in grey and to leave the other parts in white?
[image]

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always draw a [filled 2D rectangle](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/rectangle.html) with the desired color:

```
rectangle('Position',[-5,400,10,400],'FaceColor',[0.7,0.7,0.7])
```

So:

1. Put your background in white
2. Draw the gray rectangle
3. Finally draw the curve.